# Django: Operational error while running unit tests

Tags: sql, django, mariadb

We have a Django app using MariaDB 10. When I attempt to run unit tests, like so: 
`./manage.py test myapp`

the building of the test database fails with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1709, 'Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.')
```

I already know that the character set (utf8) and the collation (utf8_general_ci) on the VARCHAR(200) field are what is causing the error.

I have tried deleting all the migration files for the affected app and re-running them, but that did not fix the problem. (I'm new to python and Django, and it seemed like a good idea at the time...)

My question is: How can I fix/skip this error (and any similar errors that might occur further on in the process) so I can complete the build the test database?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the length of the field? I'm not a MySQL expert, but I understand that the max length for indexing columns can be 191 characters in some cases. However, that's for utf8mb4, and you say you're using utf8, so that might not be the problem in your case.

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and tell us what index you are trying to add.

Comment: `VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8` will not cause that error _by itself_.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the database, make sure to use `SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

For running test: in your db config add

```
'TEST_CHARSET': 'utf8',
'TEST_COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
```

If that doesn't work: change the config files

```
#/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf
default-character-set = utf8 

#/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf
default-character-set = utf8
```

... and restart the database.